# Getting columns 1 and 3 with awk and merging them into one

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a text file that contains information I need to extract in the following form:

```
 code1 something1 code2 something2 code3 something3
 code4 something4 code5 something5 code6 something6
 ...
```

And I would like to extract it into two separate documents in the form:

```
code1
code2
code3
code4
...
```

And:

```
 something1
 something2
 something3 
 something4 
 ...
```

Note that they must be ordered. Using for example `cat mydocument | awk '{print $1 $3}'` outputs

```
code1code2
code4code5
...
```

Comment: Are u sure? I think it should output code1 code2; code 3 code4; ...

Comment: @giuseppe true, corrected.

Comment: Post examples of "code"s and "something"s as your sample input/output, not just those words or you could end up with a solution that only works for input that literally contains "code" and "something" or in other ways is not a good (or functional) solution for your real data. Does your input file REALLY have a blank line between each data line? If not, fix your question to be more truly representative of your real data.

Answer (score 3):

Write columns 1,3,5,7 and so on to file code.txt and columns 2,4,6,8 and so on to file something.txt:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i=i+2) print $i}' input.txt > code.txt
awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i=i+2) print $i}' input.txt > something.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Given what you've posted so far all you need is (with GNU awk for multi-char RS):

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '{print > (NR%2?"foo":"bar")}' file
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to be clearer.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this nice command(FAN of your awk commands), though my command's logic similar to you but honestly I haven't copied it :) (before few mins it was posted)

Comment: @Ed, as per this article  (https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html#Options)  using -v  with built in  variables may lead to surprising results , so I think   `awk  'BEGIN{RS="[[:space:]]+"} {print > (NR%2?"foo":"bar")}'`  can be used

Comment: @Vicky That article is warning about the variables that awk sets while executing like NF and NR, not the ones it never sets like RS, ORS, FS, and OFS. There's nothing wrong with setting variables on the command line. The only think you need to be aware of when using `-v` is that it'll interpret escape sequences so `\t` will become a literal tab character, etc., but that doesn't apply in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `print` multiple times to output all relevant fields on separate lines :

```
awk '{print $1; print $3; print $5}' input_file > fields1_3_and_5
awk '{print $2; print $4; print $6}' input_file > fields2_4_and_6
```

If the empty lines are present in your input file as your post seems to show, you could check the number of fields to avoid getting them in your output files :

```
awk 'NF==6{print $1; print $3; print $5}' input_file > fields1_3_and_5
awk 'NF==6{print $2; print $4; print $6}' input_file > fields2_4_and_6
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's not all you need then update your question to show some more truly representative sample input and expected output.

**Input**

```
$ cat f
code1 something1 code2 something2 code3 something3

code4 something4 code5 something5 code6 something6
```

**Output**

```
$ awk 'NF{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)print $i >(i%2?"code.txt":"something.txt")}' f

$ cat code.txt 
code1
code2
code3
code4
code5
code6

$ cat something.txt 
something1
something2
something3
something4
something5
something6
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) if(i%2!=0) {print $i > "code.txt"} else{print $i > "col.txt"}}' column.txt
```

> Here you can see the output of both files -

```
paste code.txt col.txt 
code1   something1
code2   something2
code3   something3
code4   something4
code5   something5
code6   something6
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked for `awk`, other solutions are possible.

When all lines have an even nr of fields, you can do

```
grep -Eo "[^ ]+ [^ ]+" input.txt | cut -d" " -f1 > oddfields.txt
grep -Eo "[^ ]+ [^ ]+" input.txt | cut -d" " -f2 > evenfields.txt
```

or the same idea using `sed`

```
sed 's/ *\([^ ]\+\) [^ ]\+/\1\n/g' input.txt > oddfields.txt
sed 's/ *[^ ]\+ \([^ ]\+\)/\1\n/g' input.txt > evenfields.txt
```